# Parse RSS with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, rss, feedparser

I want to use jQuery to parse RSS feeds. Can this be done with the base jQuery library out of the box or will I need to use a plugin?

Comment: I would go for https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss — it's the best option right now, multiple options available! :)

Comment: For anyone landing here from google I had to create a similar thing for a deviantART thumbnail viewer. Nice and simple and easily extendible: http://www.adamjamesnaylor.com/2012/11/05/Keratin-DeviantART-Latest-Deviation-Widget.aspx. Note it makes use of google's feed reader, but only to convert it into JSON.

Comment: https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss

Answer (score 209, accepted):

**WARNING**

> [The Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/) is officially **deprecated** and **doesn't work anymore**!

---

No need for a whole plugin. This will return your RSS as a JSON object to a callback function:

```
function parseRSS(url, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      callback(data.responseData.feed);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Tried jFeed and it didn't work, this works fine and doesn't require an extra library.

Comment: I wonder about the missing API key google asks for in all it's requests.

Comment: be aware... using the google api, the feeds are cached so you wont be getting the latest and greatest feeds.

Comment: where is it cached? how can i remove cache?

Comment: what value should be passed in url

Comment: @JegBagus I had the same issue and posted my solution below

Comment: This is not a great answer. It is dependent on a third party company [Google] maintaining their service. It does not answer the original question ("Parse RSS with jQuery") and instead advertises Google. What if Google drops or modifies their ajax API? Your website breaks.

Comment: How do you apply  google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT to this example code?

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin, yes, this solution depends on a 3rd party-hosted service and therefore isn't ideal, but if you're hitting a cross-domain URL, you're going to need some kind of hosted service. According to Google's ToS (http://developers.google.com/feed/terms), this API will be available through April 2015. Yahoo also has a service (see https://github.com/AIRSHP/Feed-To-JSON/blob/master/jquery.feedToJSON.js), and there are plenty of XML-to-JSON projects on github if you want to host your own.

Comment: "solution depends on a 3rd party-hosted service and therefore isn't ideal": Well, please consider the whole World Wide Web as 3rd party-hosted oriented architecture. BTW, if you need to fetch a **mix of RSS feeds** ordered by item date, & if you're not afraid of (historical) 3rd party: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes is a great solution, outputing JSON / XML.

Comment: @CharlesGoodwin Google just removed this API! https://developers.google.com/feed/?hl=en

Comment: In case someone is interested in a drop-in replacement for the former Google Feed API, you can find such here: https://github.com/sdepold/feedrapp

Answer (score 185):

[Use jFeed](https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed) - a jQuery RSS/Atom plugin. According to the docs, it's as simple as:

```
jQuery.getFeed({
   url: 'rss.xml',
   success: function(feed) {
      alert(feed.title);
   }
});
```

Comment: any examples of real world usage? ie parsing and displaying rather than alert. or is it as simple as $("#results").append(feed.title)

Comment: NOTE: the download has all kinds of great examples in it

Comment: good answer but i can't download this plugin how i can download it because tar.gz format is not supports by my winrar

Comment: Anirudha, perhaps you can try 7-zip? It's Free, open source, and opens a variety of file types, including tar/gzip.

Comment: Please note the latest version of this plugin is available **[on Github](https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed)**.

Comment: jFeed seems to be no longer actively maintained (the last change of note is 2 years old, and many open pull requests seem to be ignored), and does not work with recent releases of jQuery.

Comment: It's on GitHub. Why not fork it and update it instead of complain about it? Maybe email the author and find out what's up.

Comment: I used jFeed a couple of years ago and had a great experience with it.

Answer (score 162):

For those of us coming to the discussion late, starting with 1.5 jQuery has built-in xml parsing capabilities, which makes it pretty easy to do this without plugins or 3rd party services.  It has a parseXml function, and will also auto-parse xml when using the $.get function.  E.g.:

```
$.get(rssurl, function(data) {
    var $xml = $(data);
    $xml.find("item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("link").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                author: $this.find("author").text()
        }
        //Do something with item here...
    });
});
```

Comment: XmlHttpRequest error: Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @jackocnr, yeah that's the downside of this method.  You can't do cross-domain requests unless you have access to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the source server.  If the server supports jsonp, then that is your best bet.  Otherwise, you might use a proxy script within your domain to retrieve the xml and then call that script instead of the external server.

Comment: Is this really the only answer that doesn't rely on external plugins or services?

Comment: Why the `$this.find("link").text()` always returns empty string ''?

Comment: @JeffTian, hard to say without seeing your xml. The most obvious reason would be that the <link> element is missing or empty.

Comment: @DavidHammond, thank you for your reply. I figured out the cause is the data returned contains some leading unvisible white spaces by using $.parseXML(data). So I resolved the issue by using `$xml = $($.parseXML(data.trim()));`, and then I can get the link as expected.

Answer (score 16):

jFeed doesn't work in IE.

Use [zRSSFeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/). Had it working in 5 minutes

Comment: Available at http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/
About to try it out myself to see how it goes, looks promising.

Comment: BTW, zRssFeed uses internally [Google Feed RSS API](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/jsondevguide.html). So if one wants to do the HTML layout itself it's easier to just look directly to that instead.

Comment: super cool... only thing is if they were providing the feed objects rather than the whole html in a callback function than that would be great...

Comment: FYI anyone looking to use this plugin. The developer posted the following.

"THIS PLUGIN IS DISCONTINUED

Due to the Google Feeds API being removed from service, which the plugin replied on, it will no longer be available or supported."

Source:
http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/

Answer (score 16):

> **Update (Oct 15, 2019)**

I extracted the core logic from jquery-rss to a new library called [Vanilla RSS](https://github.com/sdepold/vanilla-rss) which is using the fetch API and can work without any additional dependencies:

```
const RSS = require('vanilla-rss');
const rss = new RSS(
    document.querySelector("#your-div"),
    "http://www.recruiter.com/feed/career.xml",
    { 
      // options go here
    }
);
rss.render().then(() => {
  console.log('Everything is loaded and rendered');
});
```

> Original

post:

You can also use [jquery-rss](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss), which comes with nice templating and is super easy to use:

```
$("#your-div").rss("http://www.recruiter.com/feed/career.xml", {
    limit: 3,
    layoutTemplate: '<ul class="inline">{entries}</ul>',
    entryTemplate: '<li><a href="{url}">[{author}@{date}] {title}</a><br/>{shortBodyPlain}</li>'
})
```

yields (as of Sept 18, 2013):

```
<div id="your-div">
    <ul class="inline">
    <entries></entries>
    </ul>
    <ul class="inline">
        <li><a href="http://www.recruiter.com/i/when-to-go-over-a-recruiter%e2%80%99s-head/">[@Tue, 10 Sep 2013 22:23:51 -0700] When to Go Over a Recruiter's Head</a><br>Job seekers tend to have a certain "fear" of recruiters and hiring managers, and I mean fear in the reverence and respect ...</li>
        <li><a href="http://www.recruiter.com/i/the-perfect-job/">[@Tue, 10 Sep 2013 14:52:40 -0700] The Perfect Job</a><br>Having long ago dealt with the "perfect resume" namely God's, in a previous article of mine, it makes sense to consider the ...</li>
        <li><a href="http://www.recruiter.com/i/unemployment-benefits-applications-remain-near-5-year-low-decline-again/">[@Mon, 09 Sep 2013 12:49:17 -0700] Unemployment Benefits Applications Remain Near 5-Year Low, Decline Again</a><br>As reported by the U.S. Department of Labor, the number of workers seeking unemployment benefits continued to sit near ...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sdepold/ozq2dn9e/1/ for a working example.

Comment: Bear in mind that jquery-rss uses the Google Feed API which will cache the feed, which could present a problem.  You can trick it by adding a junk url parameter though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401936/prevent-google-feed-api-from-using-cached-feed

Comment: please provide an example to format date without the use of `moment.js`

Comment: Check the following snippet https://gist.github.com/sdepold/d1e5e0e7a66fc77930fe

It will generate something like this: "<some content>, [@2015-11-18]"

Comment: Just wanted to mention that jquery-rss is NOT using the Google Feed API but a drop-in replacement called Feedr (https://github.com/sdepold/feedrapp) and respectively works fine despite the original API being turned off.

Comment: Just want to mention that jquery-rss returns an error for me utilizing Feedr: "jquery-1.6.4.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blah.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://www.feedrapp.info/etcetcetc'..." I tried forcing "https:" in the script but it keeps throwing errors.

Comment: Are you willed to share more details? This should not happen if you enable the ssl option. To fully reproduce, I'd need: How do you include the script into your website, how do you use the script incl options and target RSS feed.

Answer (score 15):

[Using JFeed](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed)

```
function getFeed(sender, uri) {
    jQuery.getFeed({
        url: 'proxy.php?url=' + uri,
        success: function(feed) {
            jQuery(sender).append('<h2>'
            + '<a href="'
            + feed.link
            + '">'
            + feed.title
            + '</a>'
            + '</h2>');

            var html = '';

            for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length && i < 5; i++) {

                var item = feed.items[i];

                html += '<h3>'
                + '<a href="'
                + item.link
                + '">'
                + item.title
                + '</a>'
                + '</h3>';

                html += '<div class="updated">'
                + item.updated
                + '</div>';

                html += '<div>'
                + item.description
                + '</div>';
            }

            jQuery(sender).append(html);
        }    
    });
}

<div id="getanewbrowser">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    getFeed($("#getanewbrowser"), 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/getanewbrowser')
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Use Google AJAX Feed API unless your RSS data is private. It's fast, of course.

https://developers.google.com/feed/

Comment: A good idea, but doesn't work when you're inside a firewall which requires proxy authentication using a dialogue box.

Comment: the google feed is deprecated and not supported any more.

Answer (score 8):

> ***UPDATE*** [*4/25/2016*] Now better written and fully supported version with more options and abilities hosted at [**GitHub.jQRSS**](https://github.com/JDMcKinstry/jQRSS)

I saw the [*Selected* Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery#answer-226679) by [Nathan Strutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5918/nathan-strutz), however, the jQuery Plugin page link is still down and the home page for that site did not seem to load. I tried a few other solutions and found most of them to be, not only out-dated, but **EASY**! Thus I threw my hat out there and made my own plugin, and with the dead links here, this seems like a great place to submit an answer. If you're looking for this answer in 2012 (soon to b 2013) you may notice the frustration of dead links and old advice here as I did. Below is a link to my *modern* plugin example as well as the code to the plugin!  Simply copy the code into a JS file & link it in your header like any other plugin. Use is EXTREMELY EZ!

## jsFiddle

> **Plugin Code**
> <sub>2/9/2015 - made long overdue update to check for `console` before sending commands to it! Should help with older IE issues.</sub>

```
(function($) {
    if (!$.jQRSS) { 
        $.extend({  
            jQRSS: function(rss, options, func) {
                if (arguments.length <= 0) return false;

                var str, obj, fun;
                for (i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) {
                    switch(typeof arguments[i]) {
                        case "string":
                            str = arguments[i];
                            break;
                        case "object":
                            obj = arguments[i];
                            break;
                        case "function":
                            fun = arguments[i];
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (str == null || str == "") {
                    if (!obj['rss']) return false;
                    if (obj.rss == null || obj.rss == "") return false;
                }

                var o = $.extend(true, {}, $.jQRSS.defaults);

                if (typeof obj == "object") {
                    if ($.jQRSS.methods.getObjLength(obj) > 0) {
                        o = $.extend(true, o, obj);
                    }
                }

                if (str != "" && !o.rss) o.rss = str;
                o.rss = escape(o.rss);

                var gURL = $.jQRSS.props.gURL 
                    + $.jQRSS.props.type 
                    + "?v=" + $.jQRSS.props.ver
                    + "&q=" + o.rss
                    + "&callback=" + $.jQRSS.props.callback;

                var ajaxData = {
                        num: o.count,
                        output: o.output,
                    };

                if (o.historical) ajaxData.scoring = $.jQRSS.props.scoring;
                if (o.userip != null) ajaxData.scoring = o.userip;

                $.ajax({
                    url: gURL,
                    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) { if (window['console']) { console.log(new Array(30).join('-'), "REQUESTING RSS XML", new Array(30).join('-')); console.log({ ajaxData: ajaxData, ajaxRequest: settings.url, jqXHR: jqXHR, settings: settings, options: o }); console.log(new Array(80).join('-')); } },
                    dataType: o.output != "xml" ? "json" : "xml",
                    data: ajaxData,
                    type: "GET",
                    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { return new Array("ERROR", { jqXHR: jqXHR, textStatus: textStatus, errorThrown: errorThrown } ); },
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {  
                        var f = data['responseData'] ? data.responseData['feed'] ? data.responseData.feed : null : null,
                            e = data['responseData'] ? data.responseData['feed'] ? data.responseData.feed['entries'] ? data.responseData.feed.entries : null : null : null
                        if (window['console']) {
                            console.log(new Array(30).join('-'), "SUCCESS", new Array(30).join('-'));
                            console.log({ data: data, textStatus: textStatus, jqXHR: jqXHR, feed: f, entries: e });
                            console.log(new Array(70).join('-'));
                        }

                        if (fun) {
                            return fun.call(this, data['responseData'] ? data.responseData['feed'] ? data.responseData.feed : data.responseData : null);
                        }
                        else {
                            return { data: data, textStatus: textStatus, jqXHR: jqXHR, feed: f, entries: e };
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        $.jQRSS.props = {
            callback: "?",
            gURL: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/",
            scoring: "h",
            type: "load",
            ver: "1.0"
        };
        $.jQRSS.methods = {
            getObjLength: function(obj) {
                if (typeof obj != "object") return -1;
                var objLength = 0;
                $.each(obj, function(k, v) { objLength++; })
                return objLength;
            }
        };
        $.jQRSS.defaults = {
            count: "10", // max 100, -1 defaults 100
            historical: false,
            output: "json", // json, json_xml, xml
            rss: null,  //  url OR search term like "Official Google Blog"
            userip: null
        };
    }
})(jQuery);
```

> **USE**

```
//  Param ORDER does not matter, however, you must have a link and a callback function
//  link can be passed as "rss" in options
//  $.jQRSS(linkORsearchString, callbackFunction, { options })

$.jQRSS('someUrl.xml', function(feed) { /* do work */ })

$.jQRSS(function(feed) { /* do work */ }, 'someUrl.xml', { count: 20 })

$.jQRSS('someUrl.xml', function(feed) { /* do work */ }, { count: 20 })

$.jQRSS({ count: 20, rss: 'someLink.xml' }, function(feed) { /* do work */ })
```

<strike>$.jQRSS('Search Words Here instead of a Link', function(feed) { /* do work */ })</strike>
   // TODO: Needs fixing

> **Options**

```
{
    count: // default is 10; max is 100. Setting to -1 defaults to 100
    historical: // default is false; a value of true instructs the system to return any additional historical entries that it might have in its cache. 
    output: // default is "json"; "json_xml" retuns json object with xmlString / "xml" returns the XML as String
    rss: // simply an alternate place to put news feed link or search terms
    userip: // as this uses Google API, I'll simply insert there comment on this:
        /*  Reference: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide
            This argument supplies the IP address of the end-user on 
            whose behalf the request is being made. Google is less 
            likely to mistake requests for abuse when they include 
            userip. In choosing to utilize this parameter, please be 
            sure that you're in compliance with any local laws, 
            including any laws relating to disclosure of personal 
            information being sent.
        */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[I agree with @Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271906/30433), using Google is a solid, reusable way to do it with the huge benefit that you get JSON back instead of XML.  An added advantage of using Google as a proxy is that services that might block your direct access to their data are unlikely to stop Google.  Here is an example using ski report and conditions data.  This has all of the common real world applications: 1) Third party RSS/XML 2) JSONP 3) Cleaning strings and string to array when you can't get the data exactly the way you want it 4) on load add elements to the DOM.  Hope this helps some people!

```
<!-- Load RSS Through Google as JSON using jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displaySkiReport (feedResponse) {

    // Get ski report content strings
    var itemString = feedResponse.entries[0].content;
    var publishedDate = feedResponse.entries[0].publishedDate;

    // Clean up strings manually as needed
    itemString = itemString.replace("Primary: N/A", "Early Season Conditions"); 
    publishedDate = publishedDate.substring(0,17);

    // Parse ski report data from string
    var itemsArray = itemString.split("/");


    //Build Unordered List
    var html = '<h2>' + feedResponse.entries[0].title + '</h2>';
    html += '<ul>';

    html += '<li>Skiing Status: ' + itemsArray[0] + '</li>';
    // Last 48 Hours
    html += '<li>' + itemsArray[1] + '</li>';
    // Snow condition
    html += '<li>' + itemsArray[2] + '</li>';
    // Base depth
    html += '<li>' + itemsArray[3] + '</li>';

    html += '<li>Ski Report Date: ' + publishedDate + '</li>';

    html += '</ul>';

    $('body').append(html);    

    }


    function parseRSS(url, callback) {
      $.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      callback(data.responseData.feed);
    }
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {              

        // Ski report
        parseRSS("http://www.onthesnow.com/michigan/boyne-highlands/snow.rss", displaySkiReport);

    });

</script>
```

Comment: This is not going to work because of cross-domain issues. You need JSONP.

Comment: It works for me.  Did you test it?  Pretty sure Google returns jsonp using the callback parameter not ajax dataType.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was for. This code still works three years later. Paste it all into the console and you'll see current (XML) ski conditions added to the footer of this page.

Answer (score 5):

```
(function(url, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            callback(data.responseData.feed);
        }
    });
})('http://news.hitb.org/rss.xml', function(feed){ // Change to desired URL
    var entries = feed.entries, feedList = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        feedList +='<li><a href="' + entries[i].link + '">' + entries[i].title + '</a></li>';
    }
    jQuery('.feed > ul').append(feedList);
});


<div class="feed">
        <h4>Hacker News</h4>
        <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

jFeed is somewhat obsolete, working only with older versions of jQuery. It has been two years since it was updated.

zRSSFeed is perhaps a little less flexible, but it is easy to use, and it works with the current version of jQuery (currently 1.4). http://www.zazar.net/developers/zrssfeed/

Here's a quick example from the zRSSFeed docs:

```
<div id="test"><div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#test').rssfeed('http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/oddlyEnoughNews', {
    limit: 5
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Might note this only works with non-local feeds, since it uses the Google Feed API (Google must be able to load the feed xml).

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jFeed/build/dist/jquery.jfeed.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadFeed(){
        $.getFeed({
            url: 'url=http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/rss/news/',
            success: function(feed) {

                //Title
                $('#result').append('<h2><a href="' + feed.link + '">' + feed.title + '</a>' + '</h2>');

                //Unordered List
                var html = '<ul>';

                $(feed.items).each(function(){
                    var $item = $(this);

                    //trace( $item.attr("link") );
                    html += '<li>' +
                        '<h3><a href ="' + $item.attr("link") + '" target="_new">' +
                        $item.attr("title") + '</a></h3> ' +
                        '<p>' + $item.attr("description") + '</p>' +
                        // '<p>' + $item.attr("c:date") + '</p>' +
                        '</li>';
                });

                html += '</ul>';

                $('#result').append(html);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not a bad answer, but unfortunately you didn't do the greatest job pasting the code. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using jquery with yql for feed. You can retrieve twitter,rss,buzz with yql. I read from http://tutorialzine.com/2010/02/feed-widget-jquery-css-yql/ . It's very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

I advice you to use [FeedEk](http://jquery-plugins.net/FeedEk/FeedEk.html). After Google Feed API is officially deprecated most of plugins doesn't work. But FeedEk is still working. It's very easy to use and has many options to customize.

```
$('#divRss').FeedEk({
   FeedUrl:'http://jquery-plugins.net/rss'
});
```

With options

```
$('#divRss').FeedEk({
  FeedUrl:'http://jquery-plugins.net/rss',
  MaxCount : 5,
  ShowDesc : true,
  ShowPubDate:true,
  DescCharacterLimit:100,
  TitleLinkTarget:'_blank',
  DateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
  DateFormatLang:'en'
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can actually define an alternative api endpoint, but if you could, there would potentially be the possibility to replace the google feed api with feedrapp: https://github.com/sdepold/feedrapp (which is also the backbone for jquery-rss nowadays)

Comment: This does not do parsing. It uses yahooapis to do the parsing, then it just displays the content.

Answer (score 0):

[zRSSfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/) is built on *jQuery* and the simple theme is awesome.
Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Use [google ajax api](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide), cached by google and any output format you want.

Code sample;
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#load_feed

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=AIzaSyA5m1Nc8ws2BbmPRwKu5gFradvD_hgq6G0" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
*  How to load a feed via the Feeds API.
*/

google.load("feeds", "1");

// Our callback function, for when a feed is loaded.
function feedLoaded(result) {
  if (!result.error) {
    // Grab the container we will put the results into
    var container = document.getElementById("content");
    container.innerHTML = '';

    // Loop through the feeds, putting the titles onto the page.
    // Check out the result object for a list of properties returned in each entry.
    // http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/reference.html#JSON
    for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
      var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
  }
}

function OnLoad() {
  // Create a feed instance that will grab Digg's feed.
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.digg.com/rss/index.xml");

  // Calling load sends the request off.  It requires a callback function.
  feed.load(feedLoaded);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

Comment: this is a great option because it doesn't rely on jquery!

Answer (score 0):

[The jQuery-rss project](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss) is pretty lightweight and doesn't impose any particular styling.

The syntax can be as simple as

```
$("#rss-feeds").rss("http://www.recruiter.com/feed/career.xml")
```

See a [working example at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/AFHfn/](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/AFHfn/)

Answer (score -1):

[jQuery Feeds](https://github.com/camagu/jquery-feeds) is a nice option, it has a built-in templating system and uses the Google Feed API, so it has cross-domain support.

Answer (score -1):

[Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com) has a [jquery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/superfeedr/) which does that very well.
You won't have any Cross Origin Policy issue and the updates are propagated in realtime.

Comment: Why would this solution not have CORS issues?

Answer (score -2):

jFeed is easy and has an [example](https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed/blob/master/example.html) for you to test. But if you're parsing a feed from another server, you'll need to allow [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (CORS) on the feed's server. You'll also need to [check browser support](http://caniuse.com/cors).

I uploaded [the sample](https://raw.github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed/master/example.html) but still did not get support from IE in any version when I changed the url in the example to something like example.com/feed.rss via the http protocol. CORS should be supported for IE 8 and above but the jFeed example did not render the feed.

Your best bet is to use Google's API:
https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide

See:
https://github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
http://caniuse.com/cors