# process RSS feeds with AJAX and javascript only

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, rss, feed

Is it possible to connect to an RSS feed, retrieve the XML object then parse and display it all within client side javascript/ AJAX?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a specific reason why it all should have to be client side? A piece of Javascript can easily call a script on the server to do that work and then pass back the results to the piece of Javascript.

Comment: I prefer to do it all client side for debugging without deploying to the server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Subject to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), yes. http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1672 has an example (although, frankly, the code isn't very good, you starting hitting global variables in the first function).

Comment: So this would effectively be  able to consume a feed ONLY on the same domain?

Comment: In a standard security context — yes. You can proxy things through your own server, of course.

Comment: @Dhaivat — the question does not mention Phonegap. Are you confusing this question with [the entirely separate one that you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483804/phonegap-rss-feeds-javascript)?!

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've been commenting on the wrong answers in the wrong question.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible.

However, there are some limitations on the browser side : AJAX requests (XHR / XmlHttpRequest) can only be done **on the same domain** that hosts your javascript script(s).

It means that a script hosted on http://example.com/ cannot perform a XHR on http://domain.com/.

You can *bypass* this limitation by using a *proxy* script server-side. E.g: http://example.com/getFeed.php?feed=the_complete_url_of_the_targeted_feed

Answer (score 0):

Yep, certainly possible. A real world example follows:

```
<div id='tagged'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $.get('http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/40986', function(data){
     $(data).find('entry').each(function(){
         var $rssLink = $('<a></a>')
             .attr('href', $(this).find('link').attr('href'))
             .append($(this).find('id').text());
         var $divContainer = $('<div></div>');
         $rssLink.appendTo($divContainer);
         $divContainer.appendTo('#tagged');
     });
 });

</script>
```

Using jQuery I get my own StackOverflow rss feed and print out a link to each entry.

Comment: I would like more explanation, considering that others are saying this isn't possible due to the XHR rules. I copy/pasted your code onto a test site just now, changing the URL, and didn't get results.