# Phonegap RSS feeds, Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I need to write a PhoneGap application (with HTML5 and JS, I don't need compatibility with IE) with AJAX so that it reads an RSS feed and looks up some specific information from it. The problem I'm having is that I have I don't the best way to do an RSS feed, and jQuery can't do XML. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently made one using this tutorial : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-build-an-rss-reader-with-jquery-mobile-2/

Comment: This option wouldn't work as an app via phone gap thought would it? Mainly down to the fact that this is a web app so can run php.

Comment: It works fine through PhoneGap. There's no problem running PHP with it.

Comment: I don't actually know, I stay away from iPhone development. But the use of PHP in that tutorial should be easily possible in simple JavaScript.

Comment: It would be great if someone could do this in javascript, as it would be just what I need...

Comment: Coming in more than a year later - PHP isn't actually needed to run on the iPhone, it runs on a separate web server, which the iPhone talks to.

Answer (score 4):

I have just made a phonegap application that parses an external RSS feed using jFeed. I'll give you an example:

First, I include the following Java scripts in my index.html file:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jfeed/dist/jquery.jfeed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/my.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
```

Then, in `my.js` I use the following:

```
parseFeed();

function parseFeed() {
$.getFeed({
    url: 'http://someUrl.com',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(feed) {

    $('#feedresult').empty();

    var html = '<ul data-role="listview">';

    for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length; i++) {

        var item = feed.items[i];

        html += '<li>'
        + '<a href="#article?id='
        + i
        + '">'
        + item.title
        + '</a>'
        + '</li>';
    }

    html = html + '</ul>';

    $('#feedresult').append(html);
    $('#main').page('destroy').page();

    }});
};
```

The code then creates a listview (jQuery mobile) in my #feedresult div where each entry represents a feed item. As phonegap utilizes some sort of web view that loads all content using the file:/// protocol ( http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/b60bda03bac6e9eb ), there is no issue in doing cross domain XMLHttpRequest from phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but can be helpful to solve it in 2014 ;-).

I test many jQuery plugin to include a RSS reader, but the only this work like a charme in 1mn is [zrssfeed](http://www.zazar.net/developers/jquery/zrssfeed/)

Just add the call (after call jquery and jquery mobile) in the header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zrssfeed.min.js"></script>
```

And after start th jquery call like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#feedresult').rssfeed('http://my.wordpress.website.com/feed/', {
            limit: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope this help,
Mike

Comment: easiest feed parser for jquery i've ever used.

Answer (score 1):

What You mean jQuery can't do XML. jQuery is JavaScript and jQuery uses `XMLHttpRequest` while doing Ajax calls. See the name `XML*`. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. There is `dataType` param. You can pass `xml` to it. After that You will get dom object with all dom object methods.

You can event use it as second param to jQuery's selectors:

```
jQuery.get(url, {}, function (data) {
    var entries = $("entry", data);
    doSomething(entries);
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: Jquery does a very bad of "parsing" HTML, it just makes the .innerHTML of a tag.

Comment: First of all I am not trying to be offensive, but define "bad". Of course it is a little bit hacky, but is it slow? Because when I am using some library the only two things that interests me is: api and speed.

I have no benchmarks or something that says jQuery method is fast. It is just general curiosity.

Comment: Its bad because it interprets XML as HTML which is very dangerous, because not all valid XML is valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a RSS-to-JSON pipe, like this one here: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=2FV68p9G3BGVbc7IdLq02Q

Comment: I'm a little scared to use something that doesn't have any development activity.

Comment: It is definitely worth a try, and since its open-source, you can always fix any issues you find.