# Phonegap + jQuery Mobile, real world sample or tutorial

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

Does anyone know of a really good tutorial or sample project where Phonegap and jQuery Mobile is used for a real world example?

All the examples I found were showing fancy transitions or theming in jQuery Mobile. The Phonegap examples mostly showcases the Phonegap API.

I could not find a single example where Phonegap and jQuery Mobile was used to solve real world problems, such as writing a app that combines Phonegap and jQuery Mobile to do user input validation, saving the data, uploading data to a web service, etc.

Comment: Another "Closed" that makes no sense to me; maybe the question should have been posed nine minutes earlier, then symmetry alone would have assured its retainometric factor.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

These may not solve exactly your "real-world problems", but perhaps something useful ...

Our [web site](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials) includes PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile tutorials for a media player, barcode scanner, google maps, and OAuth.

Also, my [github page](https://github.com/paulb777) has code, but no tutorial, for two apps:

- [AppLaudApp](https://github.com/paulb777/AppLaudApp) - a run-control, debugging enabling, download complementary app to a cloud IDE
- [NameTrendz](https://github.com/paulb777/NameTrendz) - an app developed in at Android Dev Camp to do a bunch of queries about popular name data. The PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile versions are from March 2011.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It really helped. I still hope to find the 'perfect' example. If I don't get it in a day or so, I'll mark your's as an answer. Hope that's ok with you.

Comment: I found this one: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery-mobile-forms/ It's close, but the fact that the solution works, does not mean it's right?

Comment: @JacobusR did you find another useful examples about that?

Comment: @mekici Unfortunately I did not find anything truly satisfactory. I hacked my way forward :-p

Comment: Please link to the specific tutorials on your website that you think are relevant to answering this question.

Comment: @DavidMeister - Please read the first sentence of the answer. An added caveat thirteen months later, is that these examples are getting stale and I'd encourage someone to reply with something more current.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a heavy tutorial that has good stuff in it to pick out:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery_android/

Answer (score 12):

This is a nice 5-part tutorial that covers a lot of useful material:   http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch/
(Anyone else noticing a trend forming here??? hehehee )

And **this** will **definitely** be of use to all developers:
http://blip.tv/mobiletuts/weinre-demonstration-5922038
=)
Todd

**Edit**
I just finished a nice four part tutorial building an app to write, save, edit, & delete notes using jQuery mobile (only), it was very practical & useful, but it was also only for jQM.  So, I looked to see what else they had on DZone.

I'm now going to start sorting through [these search results](http://www.dzone.com/search/google/jquery%20mobile%20phonegap%20tutorial?query=jquery%20mobile%20phonegap%20tutorial&cx=010821965829155306098%3aogyaz_5nsc8&cof=FORID:11&sitesearch=).  At a glance, it looks really promising.  I remembered this post; so I thought I'd steer people to it. ㋡

Comment: Looks like a great tutorial. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 4):

you may check this http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/ and you can also check http://mobile.tutsplus.com/category/tutorials/phonegap/ which provide you with a good sample

Answer (score 2):

you may check this website:
[Phonegap RSS feeds, Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483804/phonegap-rss-feeds-javascript),
this is an example about rss reader which uses the phonegap and jquery-mobile techniques