# How can i get rss feed of multiple websites in a single page PHONEGAP?

Tags: json, html, cordova, rss, feed

I am trying to display feeds of different websites in a single page in phonegap application.
I tried all the way but yet not able to find any best solution.
If anybody done this before then please help me or guide me to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap RSS feeds, Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483804/phonegap-rss-feeds-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. But actually I want to display feeds of multiple websites in a single page. Any idea about that?