# RSS feed dashcode confusion

Tags: xcode, macos, rss, dashcode

Does anyone know how I can parse an RSS feed, but using dashcode? I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to bypass the blocking.

Comment: why do you want to use dashcode?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to parse an RSS feed using javascript which you can write using dashcode.

infact... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery) is a stack overflow article discussing the use of jQuery (a javascript library) to easily parse an rss feed: