# Get articles through RSS from Wordpress with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, rss

Is there a way to get recent articles using JavaScript from Wordpress blog? I need to show some content from the blog easy way on a static page so I think JavaScript would be fine for this.

Comment: This will only work if you're on the same domain. Otherwise no, it won't be fine.

Comment: Yes, it's just a static html site with a Wordpress blog in a separate folder domain.com/blog. What I need is to place recent entries on the main page of that static site from that blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in different domain, you cannot do this with pure javascript. You will need to use serverside proxy (for example, PHP proxy - a file which will take URL, do request and return data). After you got data, just use jQuery ability to parse XML files and write your HTML.

[Parse RSS with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery)