# Is it possible to get an rss feed using javascript client side scripting only?

Tags: php, javascript, rss, cross-domain

If I can't do this would the process for getting the data be:
1) Have my server get the rss data from the desired rss feed.
2) Have the server parse the data.  I don't know what rss looks like but I assume some parsing     is needed to display it for a user to read.
3) Send the data to the javascript client.

Comment: jQuery based: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you can use the API of Google Feed to load a RSS Feed and parse it as you need. :) I think is a interesting option.

http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/feed/v1/devguide.html#load_the_javascript_api_and_ajax_search_module

Comment: Sadly, the [Google Feed API](https://developers.google.com/feed/) is now deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Yahoo's YQL system just for this. A decent link via Google:

http://www.wait-till-i.com/2008/12/12/yql-is-so-the-bomb-to-get-web-data-as-xml-or-json/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is. A JavaScript script can't retrieve files from domains other than the one it was served from, be they RSS or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe u can.

Make an ajax request to php script, then that php script fetch the rss and then pass the result back to your javascript

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use postrank's api.  http://apidocs.postrank.com/w/page/17907957/Feed-API or http://apidocs.postrank.com/w/page/17907977/Top-Posts-API.

They have some options to filter or return only the top posts.  plus you can pass it a callback for jsonp fun.