# Creating XML from another XML based on search queries

Tags: html, xml, search, xhtml

I have a large rss that is located [here](http://rssfeed.ucoz.com/rssfeed.xml) while my site is [here](http://bfcards.edicypages.com/). I need a step by step procedure in creating a rss feed based on the search queries that users type in. The resulting rss feed should be based on the large rss feed. Is there a way to do this using xhtml, javascript or html?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this using xhtml, javascript or html?

No. You will need a server side scripting language to process the data sources, and merge them into a new one.

Comment: Surely there must be a way. Looking at http://www.shockwave.com/downloadWall.jsp, they managed to add search by using javascripts.

Comment: @UrBestFriend nope, there is no way to serve an RSS feed using Javascript. RSS clients don't understand it. You need a server-side resource to serve it

Comment: But the site I just linked uses rss feed.

Comment: @Ur where is that site serving an RSS feed using JavaScript? I don't see it

Comment: Go here: http://www.shockwave.com/cooliris/gameWall.jsp?category=downloadMostPlayed This rss is fed into the flash app when a button is clicked.

Comment: @Ur maybe, *but the RSS feed is still served from server side*. It is not created by JavaScript. You want to *serve*  an RSS feed, and that is impossible using JS. You can *parse* an existing one and output it on a web page, no problem. But you can not create a feed that RSS clients can read.

Comment: I need to create a xml similar to what I just linked to. I don't need rss clients to read it. I only need the xml so I can add search to my site. Can you check the site I linked so that we may come to an understanding of what I wanted to make. Basically, shockwave has a larger rss that they truncate based on search queries. I hope to replicate that.

Comment: @Ur this is a pretty complex thing. It would probably be best if you split it into separate steps. The first part, parsing RSS with JS, is well answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks for this. Btw do you know what the next step would be?

Comment: @Ur well, filtering the RSS and then building the results page somehow. It'll depend on what your desired end result is. Building something like that site does is pretty complex, maybe you can use some sort of a carousel to display the results but you may have to custom build the thing. It's not going to be easy!

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I finally found the simplest answer to my problem. I just used [Yahoo Pipes.](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) This would be very useful for people who can't access their servers because their sites are hosted for free AND they need the rss to contain a cross domain policy xml because they use flash. Hope some would find this resource useful. It took me a month to find it. No need for javascript or jquery.