# How to display news feed on HTML page?

Tags: jquery, rss

I have a site with a plain HTML page. I'd like to embed a news feed on it. This feed is simple RSS supplied by a Wordpress site. No need for fancy effects, tickers, scrolling, or anything; just show the last five posts. What's easiest way to do this?

I tried an iframe:

but I get Firefox messages: "Subscribe to this feed using Thunderbird" and a similar message in IE. Plus it isn't clear how I'd style the feed.

My guess is that there's a simple Javascript widget to do this. Would love to find one that uses jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse RSS with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

use [jFeed](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed) is a generic RSS/ATOM feed parser.

```
    jQuery.getFeed({
       url: 'rss.xml',
       success: function(feed) {
           alert(feed.title);
       }
   });
```