# How to show rss feed from other source on my page?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, rss

Hi i am collecting a lot of information from different websites and putting them together for personal use.

there is a rss feed link.

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/all?alt=rss&kind=photo&access=public&filter=1&q=waldorf+hilton&hl=en_US
```

How can i use it? in case of html i just take them and assign them to literals .But how can i display this .

Here is my code..

```
    Dim rssFeed As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/base/all?alt=rss&kind=photo&access=public&filter=1&q=waldorf+hilton&hl=en_US"), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim rssData As DataSet = New DataSet()
    rssData.ReadXml(rssFeed.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())

    Dim Title, Description As String
    Dim channelItems As Object() = rssData.Tables(2).Rows(0).ItemArray
    Dim titleColumn As Integer = rssData.Tables(2).Columns("title").Ordinal
    Dim descriptionColumn As Integer = rssData.Tables(1).Columns("description").Ordinal
    Title = channelItems.GetValue(titleColumn).ToString()
    Description = channelItems.GetValue(descriptionColumn).ToString()

    Repeater1.DataSource = rssData.Tables(2)
    Repeater1.DataBind()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this on the web page or inside a vb.net application?

For a webpage: [Parse RSS with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery)

For vb.net, here's one solution: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4577

Comment: only gettin two values in dataset ...
version     2.0 
i think something wrong with the feed not properly built?

Comment: I tries with the above method same i get two values , rss version   2