# Load XML File from an RSS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, rss

I need to load an XML File from a RSS in JavaScript. Can someone show a proper example or points to a tutorial that works??

Comment: RSS is XML with a particular schema. So what do you mean by `load an XML File from a RSS`? I mean if you have an RSS you already have XML, so what is it that you are asking in particular?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers typically prevent Javascript from dynamically loading an XML RSS feed unless that feed is on the same domain. You can load JSON data, though, e.g.

```
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) { dosomethingwithdata; });
```