# show recent wordpress post on static html page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, require

I have a site that is done in HTML/PHP, mostly using static .html files.

I added a blog, and would like to grab the posts from it to display in the sidebar of the homepage.

I've followed [this guide](http://chinmoy29.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/display-latest-post-on-static-php-page/) to do so.

The problem is its not working, and I'm not 100% certain if the correct wordpress file is being pointed to.

The blog is kept in a directory called wordpress.
So my statement looks like this:
`require('wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');`

Is there something wrong with this? Is there a way to check using chrome if the file has been found / loaded?

Thanks

Comment: what type of file is your home page?

Comment: You won't be able to do this on a "static html" page. What does your file look like?

Comment: ah, maybe thats the problem. I have it set as .html, I'll try changing the extension.

Comment: and indeed, that was it. I knew i was forgetting something. Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: Just a clarification, you can also adjust your apache config file (or htaccess file) go parse html files as if they were php files. And if you didn't want to go this route, but you wanted to keep the .html extension, you could use an iframe OR use javascript/ajax to load the content into an empty element on the page

Answer (score 0):

If you intend on sticking solely to static HTML pages, the tutorial you mentioned will not help you. Your only option here is to fetch your blog posts from an RSS feed or a JSON feed using JavaScript. I would go for the latter since it's easier to deal with (especially if you utilise jQuery).

Here's a few things for you to check out or read up on:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

[Parse RSS with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery)