# How do I put this RSS feed in a jQuery listview?

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, rss, jsfiddle

Okay I found this RSS plugin and I want to display it inside a webpage, but I want it to be in a jQuery listview, so each item is a list item, could someone please explain to me how to do it? I put the jsfiddle link below! Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/8qhZP/
And this is the actual source where I found the plugin
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-rss-feed-display-live/

Comment: Not quite yet! I'll be sure to reward the bounty soon tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to accomplish this is to get the RSS feed converted into a JSON object. This way you can call the url using JSONP and then parse the output using a jQuery template engine.

1) Convert the RSS feed into a JSON feed using Yahoo pipes (can also combine RSS feeds)

http://jquery4u.com/rss/

into

[Yahoo JSON Pipe Output](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=f5e0edec7594378e719cf18c53f8a26c&_render=json)

2) Render the JSON feed using a jQuery templating engine like [json2html](http://json2html.com)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://json2html.com/js/jquery.json2html-2.5-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var transform = {tag:'li',children:[
                    {tag:'a',src:'.link',html:'.title'},
                    {tag:'br'},
                    {tag:'span',html:'.description'}
                ]};

$.getJSON("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_callback=?", {"_id":"f5e0edec7594378e719cf18c53f8a26c","_render":"json"}, function(data){
    $('#rssFeed').json2html(data.value.items,transform);
});   
</script>

<ul id='rssFeed'></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not forced to use the [jquery feed rss live plugin](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-rss-feed-display-live/) you point out, then you could use that [other plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jFeed): Parse RSS with jQuery.

It's also discussed on another post on stackoverflow: [parse rss with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery) with examples and some documentation.

So, reusing the example given by [Nathan Strutz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5918/nathan-strutz) 
you could just do something like:

```
   jQuery.getFeed({
      url: 'your url',
      success: function(feed) {
         //append your list element and then refresh the list
         $('#myList').append('<li>'+feed.title+'</li>');
         $('#myList').listview('refresh');
      }
   });
```

Hope it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The RSS plugin seems to generate a list by default. The [demo page](http://jquery4u.com/demos/jquery-rss-feed/) generates paragraphs, but that's because it's explicitly configured to do that in the source with this line:

`newsfeed.setentrycontainer("p");`

Taking this line out of the config should generate the html list.

I don't know much about the jQuery listview (it's for mobile pages right?), but I guess that if you initialise the jQuery listview **after** the RSS feed is loaded, it should work.

Good luck!