# Getting Yahoo! Finance RSS using JQuery and Google API error

Tags: jquery, rss, google-api, yahoo

Trying to get RSS from Yahoo! Finance based on answers from Andrew and Dylan Valade in [Parse RSS with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery) but receiving an error:

data.responseData is null

success()
data = Object { responseDetails="Feed could not be loaded.", responseStatus=400, responseData=null}

Loading the same URL from the browser or PHP cURL returns the RSS data ok

url: http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=^FTSE,
url encode: http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.finance.yahoo.com%2Frss%2F2.0%2Fheadline%3Fs%3D%5EFTSE

Testing from local vhost on my Mac (OS X 10.5.8, XAMPP 1.7.3). I tried zRSSfeed plugin wich also use Google API, and received the same error: "Feed could not be loaded". Index data and chart are working fine

Thanks in advance

---

```
function getRSS(symbol, url, callback) {
    $('#rss').html('http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s='+symbol+'<br />');
    $('#rss').append(encodeURIComponent(url));
    $.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
        success:
            function (data) {
                callback(data.responseData.feed);
            },
        error:
            function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#rss').append('<span class="downVal">'+textStatus+'</span>');
                $('#rss').append('<br />'+'<span class="downVal">'+errorThrown+'</span>');
            }
    });
}

function parseRSS(newsFeed) {
    $('#rss').append(newsFeed);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
...
    summary(symbol);
    $('#chart').html('<img style="-webkit-user-select:none" src="http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s='+symbol+'&t=3m&q=l&l=on&z=m&p=m20,m200,v&a=r14,m26-12-9">');
    getRSS(symbol, 'http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s='+symbol, parseRSS);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to point out is that the feed is returning a 400 code - so according to [W3C recommendations, you shouldn't repeat the call](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

> 10.4.1 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

When I open the url:

```
http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=^FTSE
```

I get a 404 error, so perhaps the search isn't always valid or is rate limited?

If you're convinced that the call is OK, then there is probably a problem with the line that calls the feed:

```
$('#rss').html('http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s='+symbol+'<br />'
```

So strip it back, alert out the symbol variable to make sure it is what you want, add lines like the following for some rudimentary debugging:

```
alert (symbol);
var feedUrl = 'http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s='+symbol;
alert (feedUrl);
```

... and finally check if appending the `<br />` is actually breaking the feed url.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, it helped me to found the problem. Region and language url paramerts are mandatory while I thought they were optional as I got confused by the documentation: "Then you're able to localize the feed results with a language/region". Besides, you must urlencode the "^" char wich point out it's an index, not a stock; I'd done in my code but omitted that line in the post. So, the right url is: http://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=%5EFTSE&region=US&lang=en-US