# change webpage every 30 seconds from rss link

Tags: php, javascript, html, rss

I want to be able to grab the links from an rss feed and display the page for 30 seconds so rss feed get first link display that for 30 sec then move on to the next one until the end and if at the end refresh the page and do it again...

how would one go about doing such thing html php javascript could anyone point me in the right direction for this to be accomplished or if there is solutions out there already

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery

Comment: I haven't tried any code i just cant figure out a way to parse a link from rss and then open that webpage and then 30 seconds change the page to the next one in the rss

Comment: You need to load the RSS through AJAX and that needs to be done within a setInterval loop that runs your code every 30 seconds. The webpage DOM update should be done within that loop too. Combined with Zachary's suggestion on how to parse RSS with jQuery and my answer, you should have a good start on the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try putting your code in a setInterval loop like this:

```
var refresh = setInterval(30000, function() {
   var obj = $.ajax({
    url: 'url', 
    data: { data }, 
    type: 'GET',
        }).done(function(msg) {
       console.log('ajax asynchronous request finished');
      });
   var rss = obj.responseText;
});
```