# need help in atom feed using jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've been trying to make atom feed work using jQueryMobile since last night but no luck. 
I am working the code locally.

I am using this scripts provided in jQueryMobile site

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

I tried a lot of code and I end up using the code answered in this question [Parse RSS with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery)

this is my code

```
function refreshFeed2() {
    $.get("resp2.xml", function (data) { 
        var $xml = $(data);
        $xml.find("item").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("link").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                author: $this.find("author").text()
            }
            alert(item.title);
        });
    });
}
```

at the end, I tried popping up an alert but it's not showing anything.

what's wrong in the code?

--- update ---
I am working with mobile devices
--- update ---
for the sake debugging. here's an updated code

```
function refreshFeed2() {
    alert("start call");

    $.get("resp.xml", function (data) {
        alert("start parse");

        var $xml = $(data);

        alert("set data");

        $xml.find("item").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
            item = {
                title: $this.find("title").text(),
                link: $this.find("link").text(),
                description: $this.find("description").text(),
                pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                author: $this.find("author").text()
            }
            alert(item.title);
        });
    });

    alert("end call");
}
```

so I added alerts .. the problem there is
it only popups in "start call" and "end call". 
My sample xml looks like this.. but this is actually a lot longer

```
<rss    version="2.0" 
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" 
        xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/">
    <channel>
        <title>title of the feed</title>
        <atom:link href="http://www.mainlink.com/livefeed" rel="self" />
        <link>http://www.mainlink.com/</link>
        <description>
        </description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <pubDate>Fri, 06 Jul 2012 04:47:51 +0800</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Fri, 06 Jul 2012 04:47:51 +0800</lastBuildDate>
        <item>
            <title>title1</title>
            <link>http://www.link1.com/</link>
            <description>desc1</description>
            <pubDate>Fri, 06 Jul 2012 04:47:09 +0800</pubDate>
            <guid>25542832</guid>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>title2</title>
            <link>http://www.link1.com/</link>
            <description>desc2</description>
            <pubDate>Fri, 06 Jul 2012 04:47:09 +0800</pubDate>
            <guid>25542831</guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop a breakpoint in there and step through the code execution. If your alert isn't showing that means either 1) the $.get request failed so your 'success' function will never get called or 2) your success function is getting called but it doesn't get to the alert because one of the `find` or `text` calls throws an exception.

Comment: fantastic.  you'll still have to drop in a breakpoint and step through the code execution to find out which of the two possible problems I mentioned is occuring.  we can't tell you, for example, whether "resp2.xml" is the correct url for your file or whether your server is properly configured to return that file

Comment: it worked in my website http://www.jaysonragasa.net/files/test/index.html but not locally.. anyway..

Comment: since I want to run this locally because I am running PhoneGap for windows phone and therefore, the xml has to be a local file.. interestingly, it worked on IE, but not in Chrome