# Dynamically setting bar graph values from a XML source

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

I got some great help parsing some RSS into a menu yesterday using jQuery [Parse RSS feed with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29818858/parse-rss-title-into-html-using-javascript), and inspired by this I would like to use something similar to control some chart bars on a website.

Some background:

> We are aiming to use a floating score in our upcoming tech reviews on
>   a webpage, meaning that you assign a product an absolute score (lets
>   say 67) and then the maximum score would be able to move as new and
>   better products hit the market. This way you would still be able to
>   read a review from last year and use the score for something
>   meaningful, as the score of 67 is now measured against this years
>   max-score. Hope it makes sense.

Anyhow, our CMS only permits javascript to be embedded in news entries, so I can't store our review scores in SQL or use php, and I was thinking of using XML instead (not optimal, but it should work). Each review would then contain a certain number of results including the beforementioned final score (and some intermediate sub-scores as well). I need to be able to insert a piece of JS code that extracts the scores for a specific review from the XML file and inserts the HTML code needed to draw the bars.

I have a JSfiddle set up, that contains the XML, it has the chart (hardcoded though), and using the jQuery code from my previous question I can sort of extract the results, but the code loops through all the XML and I don't really have a clue how to pick out the specific review number I need nor how to get things measured against the max-score, so it just prints everything right now and calculates a score based on a max-score of 100. I haven't tied the values to my chart yet, so the test version just prints the results in a ul/li.

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TorbenRasmussen/sLxdfyj7/35/)

So basically I need some sort of code that I can invoke from my HTML that goes along the lines of

```
ShowScores(testno)
```

that would write everything inside the first

```
<div class="row">..</row>
```

containing the bars, where the %-width of the bars would be calculated as the score assigned divided by the maxscore:

- Each item has 3 assigned scores: scorePicture, scoreFeature, scoreUI, and 1 calculated total score (weighted average)
- A global max score exists for each of the 3 scores: topscorePicture, topscoreFeature, topscoreUI

As I suck at JS, I have spent 5 hours getting to this point, and I have no clue how to make things load from e.g. a `testscore.xml` file instead and then extract what I need with jQuery - and I probably also need some help making my HTML load the script i.e. how to invoke it afterwards. [The documentation on jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) is concerned with loading all content in the XML and not just a specific node?

All help is appreciated.

My own thoughts on some pseudo code would be a script that, when envoked from my HTML document would do something like

```
function(reviewNo)
var max1 = load maxscore1 from XML
var max2 = load maxscore2 from XML
var max3 = load maxscore3 from XML

var score1 = load assignedscore1 for reviewNo from XML
var score2 = load assignedscore2 for reviewNo from XML
var score3 = load assignedscore2 for reviewNo from XML

Calculate % width of bar 1, bar 2 and bar 3 and save as variables as math.round()
write HTML DIV code and subsitute the width of the bars with the calculated values from above
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured that jQuery was not going to give me what I needed, so I turned to plain JS loading the XML with

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // code for IE5 and IE6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

I then use the code in my HTML as:

```
<script>
    // Which test no should be loaded
    var testNo = 1;

    //Load the XML
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("testscores.xml");

    //Extract the highest score for picture
    tsp=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("topscorePicture")[0];
    topspvalue= tsp.childNodes[0];

    //Extract highest score for features
    tsf=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("topscoreFeature")[0];
    topsfvalue= tsf.childNodes[0];

    //Extract highest score for UI
    tsui=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("topscoreUI")[0];
    topsuivalue= tsui.childNodes[0];

    //Extract  picture score for the specific test no.
    sp=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("scorePicture")[testNo];
    spvalue=sp.childNodes[0];

    //Extract Feature score for the specific test no.
    sf=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("scoreFeature")[testNo];
    sfvalue=sf.childNodes[0];

    //Extract UI score for the specific test no.
    sui=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("scoreUI")[testNo];
    suivalue=sui.childNodes[0];

    //Calculate current scores
    scorePicture = Math.round(Number(spvalue.nodeValue)/Number(topspvalue.nodeValue)*100);
    scoreFeature = Math.round(Number(sfvalue.nodeValue)/Number(topsfvalue.nodeValue)*100);
    scoreUI = Math.round(Number(suivalue.nodeValue)/Number(topsuivalue.nodeValue)*100);
    scoreTotal = Math.round(0.5*scorePicture + 0.25*scoreFeature + 0.25*scoreUI);

    //Construct HTML
    HTMLchunkStart = "<div style=\"float: Right; text-align: right; width: 40px; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; color: #666;\"><i class=\"fa fa-picture-o\"></i></div><div class=\"progress\" style=\"background-color:#E2E2E2\">";
    pictureBar = "<div class=\"progress-bar\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\""+Number(spvalue.nodeValue)+"\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\""+Number(topspvalue.nodeValue)+"\" style=\"width:"+ scorePicture+"%"+";\">"+scorePicture+"%</div>";
    HTMLchunk1 =  "</div> <div style=\"float: Right; text-align: right; width: 40px; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; color: #666;\"><i class=\"fa fa-cogs\"></i></div><div class=\"progress\" style=\"background-color:#E2E2E2\">";
    featureBar = "<div class=\"progress-bar\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\""+Number(sfvalue.nodeValue)+"\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\""+Number(topsfvalue.nodeValue)+"\" style=\"width:"+ scoreFeature+"%"+";\">"+scoreFeature+"%</div>";
    HTMLchunk2 = " </div><div style=\"float: Right; text-align: right; width: 40px; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; color: #666;\"><i class=\"fa fa-user\"></i></div><div class=\"progress\" style=\"background-color:#E2E2E2\">";
    UIbar= "<div class=\"progress-bar\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\""+Number(suivalue.nodeValue)+"\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\""+Number(topsuivalue.nodeValue)+"\" style=\"width:"+ scoreUI+"%"+";\">"+scoreUI+"%</div>";
    HTMLchunk3 =  "</div> <div style=\"padding-top: 3px;float: Right; text-align: right; width: 40px; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; color: #666;\"><i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i></div><div class=\"progress progress-lg\" style=\"background-color:#E2E2E2;height: 30px;\">"; 
    totalBar =  "<div class=\"progress-bar progress-bar-info\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\""+scoreTotal+"\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\"100\" style=\"width:"+ scoreTotal+"%"+";padding-top: 4px;\">"+scoreTotal+"%</div>";

    //Write the HTML
    document.write(HTMLchunkStart + pictureBar + HTMLchunk1+featureBar+HTMLchunk2+UIbar+HTMLchunk3+totalBar);
</script>
```

Currently I put this directly in my HTML, but I would like to put it in a separate file and simply call the code by e.g.

```
<script>showScore(1)</script>
```

To get the second entry in the XML. I am so close, but I would like a push in the right direction on how to make my code into a function that can accept a single input, which would be used as the "testNo" variable and then return all the HTML-code I have in my document.write at the end.

I also realise that my JS might not be the most efficient nor pretty, so any advice regarding clean-up is also welcome.

Another feature that comes to mind, would be the possibility to change the color of the bars according to the score. The current "progress-bar" class is just plain blue, but I could append another class to only change the colour. In my mind this would be possible by creating some classes for colours and then dependent on the % score the appropriate colour class would be added to the HTML code. If someone has an idea on how to do this I would also appreciate some input. Would I use a switch to pick the class names from an array or what?

Answer (score 0):

Alright... talking a bit to myself here, but in the spirit of telling the entire story to anyone who might venture in here in the future, the current piece of code now uses a switch to set the HTML color for each of the four bars and the code is then inserted using the code described above, tossed into a function that is invoked using

```
<script>showScore(reveiwNo);</script>
```

inside my HTML. It works pretty well. I would like to link to the final code, but it is being used on our working templates for our new website, so I would rather keep them to myself until the site goes live - and I am not trying to advertise either.