# Outputting XML with JQuery/AJAX script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

I have an RSS file, and I'm trying to use JQuery to read though the file and print the contents to an HTML page.

The RSS file looks like this:

```
<contents>
   <item>
     <title>Title</title>
     <author>Author</author>
     <description>Description</description>
   </item>
   <item>
     <title>Title</title>
     <author>Author</author>
     <description>Description</description>
   </item>
</contents>
```

My JQuery code so far looks like this and I SOLVED IT MYSELF, so cancel the question, and here's the solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $.ajax({
      url: 'file.rss', 
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseXML,
      error: function(){alert("Error: Something is wrong");}
    });

  function parseXML(document){


  $(document).find('content').each(function(){
     $(this).find('item').each(function(){
     var author =  item.find('author').text();
     var description = item.find('description').text();


     var output = description + title + author;
      $(#div).html(output);
```

But the output isn't what I want!  I want the code to loop through every entry in the RSS feed and each entry out separately, like this:

```
Title, Author
Description

Title, Author
Description
```

Instead, what's happening is that I'm getting all the titles and authors together, like this:

```
Title, Title
Author, Author
Description, Description
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You seem to have left out the part of the code that's creating the problematic output. Or any output.

Comment: Aside from the missing code, this seems likely to be a duplicate question, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7067582/4258817

Comment: I've edited the code above for clarity.

Mousey, thanks for the link -- unfortunately, it doesn't address my question.  I've taken the steps suggested, but the output just isn't right. I'm  having a tough time figuring out how to loop through the array of <item> nodes, rather than looping through each individual node inside of <item>.