# Cannot replace class on the fly from localStorage in jQuery RSS Feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rss, local-storage

I'm trying to fill RSS feed with add to fav utility using jQuery and HTML5 localStorage. What I'm trying to achieve is when a user clicks on `glyphicon-star-empty` available on title of post, it changes to `glyphicon-star` (which is done) but it should store the selected/favorited item in `localStorage` and on refresh instead of showing `glyphicon-star-empty`, it should fetch data from localStorage regarding which item is favorited and show `glyphicon-star` instead.

The problem i'm facing is in the last part. I can store fav items in localStorage but I don't seem to find the correct way to replace `glyphicon-star-empty` with `glyphicon-star` on the fly for favorited items when the page is refreshed.

the **other problem** is that when user clicks on `glyphicon-bookmark` (available near the heading -RSS) it should show all the favorited items and should also remove items from localStorage and current page on deselection (i.e clicking `glyphicon-star`)

here is the complete code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehqefk6j/).

and here is the **jquery** function i'm working on:

```
function blogRSS(url, container) {
var content = $('.data-content'); //console.log(content);


$.ajax({
  url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
  dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data.responseData.feed);


  $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(key, value) {
    var thehtml = '<h4><a href="' + value.link + '" target="_blank">' + value.title + '</a></h4>';

    $("body").append(itemLayout);

          $('.panel-heading').last().html(thehtml);
          $('.data-content').last().html(value.content);

          $('.data-title').last().next().slideToggle(0);
      //console.log($('.panel-heading').last().html(value.title));
       //console.log($('.panel-heading').closest('.data-title').text());
       if(localStorage.favorite != null){
           arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.favorite);
           for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
              // console.log($('.panel-heading').last().text() == arr[i].title);
               if($('.panel-heading').text() == arr[i].title){
                   console.log('match');
                   $('.bkmark_icon').removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
                   $('.bkmark_icon').addClass('glyphicon-star');
                   //console.log('match');
               }
           }


       }

  }); $('.data-title').find('h4').addClass('panel-title');
```

Comment: The problem is you are looping over the local storage array . You should loop over the $(.panel-heading) object and set them to the required class

Comment: Also it seems the title has an extra space at the end which is being stored in the local storage and hence they are not matching

Comment: ah right. silly me! it works.
but how about the **other problem**, i still don't find valid solution for it..

Answer (score 1):

Add a change like this inside the for loop,Basically you need to loop over each list element as well as for loop over the array to set it.

```
   $( ".panel-heading" ).each( function( index, element ){                   
                   if($(this).text() == arr[i].title.trim()){                                            
                       $(this).next().removeClass('glyphicon-star-empty');
                       $(this).next().addClass('glyphicon-star');

                   }

          });
```

Here is a modified JSfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/ehqefk6j/2/